# Redhat 6.6 root partition is showing 100% full after power failure

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I'm running Redhat 6.6 and experienced a power failure over the holiday weekend.  The / partition is showing 100% full. How do I check to see which files are actually causing the overusage?

```
[root@sms1 ~]# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_sms1-lv_root
                       53G   51G     0 100% /
tmpfs                  34G     0   34G   0% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`du -sh *` from `/` will give you the top level directory using the most space, but it might not be very quick.

Once you have a good candidate, you can change into that directory, and do another `du -sh *` to see which has the most content, and drill down.

Or, you could use `find` and specify a file size if you think it's one big file that's causing the issue.  This command finds all files over 500MB starting in `/` and working down the full directory tree.

`find / -type f -size +500000k -exec ls -lh {} \;`

Comment: I found some huge .gz files in /store. Removing those recovered enough space to start mysqld for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look for the directories with the largest consumption:

```
du -kx / | sort -rnk1,1
```

This reports in 1K blocks, sorted from highest to lowest usage.  The '-x' option prevents crossing mountpoints.

Comment: [root@ ]# du -kx / | sort -rnk1,1 | more
25569866 /
15335332 /var
8625364 /var/www
8624148 /var/www/html
8619396 /var/www/html/images

This shows that / has used the most blocks, which I already know.  I'm needing to figure out what I can delete to free up the space.

Comment: You need to assess subordinate directories (like '/var/www/' that constitute significant usage).  You are not concerned with the '/' directory (obviously).